# Office 365 XOAUTH2 for IMAP Authentication fails from standalone java code

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, office365

I am trying to connect an outlook mail box using imap .

scope defined for app is :
[API Permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLyWx.png)

I am generating the token using client credential flow :

Below is the request i am posting to get the access token.

```
grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=MyClientID&client_secret=Mysecret&scope=https://outlook.office.com/.default
```

I received token successfully.

Here's the code, used to connect to IMAP from Java:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
props.put("mail.imap.auth.login.disable", "true");
props.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
props.put("mail.debug.auth", "true");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
session.setDebug(true);
String accessToken = "access_token_received_on_previous_step";
final Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "user@outlook.com", accessToken);
```

Receiving below error:

```
A1 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 dXNlcj1zb29yeW.........
A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

Could anyone please help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

You assigned an **Microsoft Graph** **delegated permission** `IMAP.AccessAsUser.All` in Azure AD app. But **delegated permission** is not supported for **client_credentials** grant type.

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#get-an-access-token):

> OAuth access to IMAP, POP, SMTP AUTH protocols via OAuth2 client
> credentials grant flow is not supported.

And you need to use [OAuth2 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) or [OAuth2 Device authorization grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code).

Besides, I think you may need to set the `scope` as `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` because the permission is under Microsoft Graph now.

Comment: ,Thanks for the update . yes client_credentials grant type not support delegated permission .Could you please let me know whether we will be able to  generate auth code from standalone java code ,  from documentation i understood it requires a sign in  to identity platform

Comment: @SooryaP It should be feasible. See [Install the Microsoft Graph Java SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-java-sdk) and [Authorization code provider with java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java#authorization-code-provider).

Comment: Hello @AllenWu now it's supported for IMAP and POP protocols if trust that doc, but I still getting javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: AUTHENTICATE failed.